# Takes exactly 2 arguments 1 given Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got this code:

```
from yellowgod import client
client = Client(address, priv)
price = client.get_order_books('prezels')
```

yellowgod:

```
def get_order_books(self):
 return self._post2('returnOrderBook')
```

_post2:

```
    def _post2(self, path, signed=False, **kwargs):
    return self._request2('post', path, signed, **kwargs)
```

_request2:

```
    def _request2(self, method, path, signed, **kwargs):

    kwargs['json'] = kwargs.get('json', {})
    kwargs['headers'] = kwargs.get('headers', {})

    uri2 = self._create_uri2(path)

    if signed:
        # generate signature e.g. {'v': 28 (or 27), 'r': '0x...', 's': 
        '0x...'}
        kwargs['json'].update(self._generate_signature(kwargs['hash_data']))

        # put hash_data into json param
        for name, value, _param_type in kwargs['hash_data']:
            kwargs['json'][name] = value

        # filter out contract address, not required
        if 'contract_address' in kwargs['json']:
            del(kwargs['json']['contract_address'])

        # remove the passed hash data
        del(kwargs['hash_data'])

    response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri2, **kwargs)
    return self._handle_response(response)
```

The error is:

> Takes exactly 2 arguments 1 given Python

I don't understand, I'm using the get_order_books with 1 argument, why does it say I'm requesting with 2?

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Side-note: `del` is a keyword, not a function, and should not use parens (same as `return`, `yield`, etc.). `del(kwargs['hash_data'])` is misleading/poor style; just use `del kwargs['hash_data']`.